# How to display raw data from CSV in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, formatting

When I open a CSV file in Excel, data is formatted into values that aren't useful.

For example, I have a CSV with raw data

```
id,        studyid, studystartdatetime,      19960333152518,     19960444074329
10219922,  330732,  2020-10-26 07:22:03.000, 13.728111605495413, 0.8199649107182145
10222451,  331814,  2020-11-03 10:28:10.000, 43.369795528728545, 0.8648709765481933
```

and when I open this in Excel, it shows me

```
id,        studyid, studystartdatetime,   2E+13,     2E+13
10219922,  330732,  22:03.0,              13.72811,  0.81996
10222451,  331814,  28:10.0,              43.36979,  0.86487
```

How can I disable any type of formatting that occurs and view the raw data? There is going to be hundreds of columns in the CSVs I am using, so reformatting each column is not an option.

Comment: Import the data as text. Or, don't use Excel, which is IMO terrible with CSV files.

Comment: I tried that but Excel doesn't recognize the first row in the CSV as the columns names. As for using Excel, I don't have much of a say in that.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to `Data -> From Text/CSV`
2. Choose your CSV file from File Explorer
3. Select `Transform Data`
4. Select all cells with `Ctrl-A`
5. Click `Use First Row as Headers`
6. Click `Datatype: Any` and select `Text` and click `Replace current`, if prompted.
7. Click `Close and Load`

Answer (score 0):

I was also needing to be able to manage and work with CSV Data without destroying the format as Excel is so famously known for.  I find the the NEW Import Wizards are not conducive to a basic CSV Import - at least I didn't find it useful due to my not having the ability of importing the RAW Data.

Basically I'm using Excel Office 365 version 16 at the time of writing.  I had to turn on the LEGACY CSV/Text Import Wizard... I hope Microsoft NEVER gets rid of this wizard without first providing an easier method to import raw data.

Using the below method I have no issues removing rows or columns after first making sure I have imported ALL columns as TEXT... when you save your changes be sure to save it as a CSV file.

**Turn On Legacy Wizard:**

In Excel navigate to File --> Options --> Data --> Check the box in the 'Show legacy data import wizards' section 'From Text (Legacy)'

**Now to import your CSV or RAW Text File**

Navigate to the Data Tab and within the 'Get & Transform Data' section choose Get Data --> Legacy Wizards --> From Text (Legacy).

**Gif Showing how to turn on Legacy Import:**
[image: Turn on CSV Legacy Import]

**Gif Showing how to import CSV Data:**
[image: Import CSV Data]

Hopefully this will help somebody else.